# Is there a way to speed up this Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I suspect there is a way to make this faster, but it's beyond my MySQL limitations.

I have a table which is comprised of data collected from some sensors, at a rate of 1Hz on activity by activity basis.  The table columns are activityId, transducerId (which sensor the data is from), the value the sensor is reporting, and the timestamp.  A given activity can have 0 - 24 sensors.

One second of data looks like this (give or take rows depending on number of sensors):
  [image]

I need to get a new table with columns named for each sensor containing the data for that sensor, and the datetime column.  For example:

[image]

Currently I'm getting this table with a very long series of queries and joins.  Here's the query I'm using:

```
SELECT cd.calculatedValue AS `301`, q1.`302` , q2.`303` , q3.`304` , q4.`305` , q5.`306` , q6.`307` , q7.`308` , q8.`309` , q9.`310` , q10.`311` , q11.`312` , q12.`313` , q13.`314` , cd.`datetime` 
FROM 
data cd 
JOIN 
(SELECT `calculatedValue` AS `302`, `datetime` FROM `data` WHERE `activityId` = 74 AND `transducerId` = 302) AS q1 
ON cd.`datetime` = q1.`datetime` 
JOIN 
(SELECT `calculatedValue` AS `303`, `datetime` FROM `data` WHERE `activityId` = 74 AND `transducerId` = 303) AS q2 
ON cd.`datetime` = q2.`datetime` 
JOIN 
(SELECT `calculatedValue` AS `304`, `datetime` FROM `data` WHERE `activityId` = 74 AND `transducerId` = 304) AS q3 
ON cd.`datetime` = q3.`datetime` 
JOIN 
(SELECT `calculatedValue` AS `305`, `datetime` FROM `data` WHERE `activityId` = 74 AND `transducerId` = 305) AS q4 
ON cd.`datetime` = q4.`datetime` 
JOIN 
(SELECT `calculatedValue` AS `306`, `datetime` FROM `data` WHERE `activityId` = 74 AND `transducerId` = 306) AS q5 
ON cd.`datetime` = q5.`datetime` 
JOIN 
(SELECT `calculatedValue` AS `307`, `datetime` FROM `data` WHERE `activityId` = 74 AND `transducerId` = 307) AS q6 
ON cd.`datetime` = q6.`datetime` 
JOIN 
(SELECT `calculatedValue` AS `308`, `datetime` FROM `data` WHERE `activityId` = 74 AND `transducerId` = 308) AS q7 
ON cd.`datetime` = q7.`datetime` 
JOIN 
(SELECT `calculatedValue` AS `309`, `datetime` FROM `data` WHERE `activityId` = 74 AND `transducerId` = 309) AS q8 
ON cd.`datetime` = q8.`datetime`
 JOIN 
 (SELECT `calculatedValue` AS `310`, `datetime` FROM `data` WHERE `activityId` = 74 AND `transducerId` = 310) AS q9 
 ON cd.`datetime` = q9.`datetime` 
 JOIN 
 (SELECT `calculatedValue` AS `311`, `datetime` FROM `data` WHERE `activityId` = 74 AND `transducerId` = 311) AS q10 
 ON cd.`datetime` = q10.`datetime` 
 JOIN 
 (SELECT `calculatedValue` AS `312`, `datetime` FROM `data` WHERE `activityId` = 74 AND `transducerId` = 312) AS q11 
 ON cd.`datetime` = q11.`datetime` 
 JOIN 
 (SELECT `calculatedValue` AS `313`, `datetime` FROM `data` WHERE `activityId` = 74 AND `transducerId` = 313) AS q12 
 ON cd.`datetime` = q12.`datetime` 
 JOIN 
 (SELECT `calculatedValue` AS `314`, `datetime` FROM `data` WHERE `activityId` = 74 AND `transducerId` = 314) AS q13 
 ON cd.`datetime` = q13.`datetime` 
 WHERE cd.`activityId` = 74 AND cd.`transducerId` = 301
```

This takes a very long time on just minutes of data, and realistically there will be hours of data in the table, as well as up to 10 more sensors.

Is there a better way to do this query?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would say not since you are transposing the table (converting rows to columns). You should really design the tables the way you need them displayed, or do some post processing to display the results, you are going nowhere with that approach. But this is only my opinion.

Comment: Also, can you show indices from `data` table?

Comment: MySQL does not have a PIVOT function like MSSQL or it might make this a little bit easier.  Still, as @D.Kasipovic says, change your data structure to better handle your ideas.

Comment: Don't confuse data retrieval with data display

Comment: @D.Kasipovic I haven't defined any indices for the `data` table other than `PRIMARY KEY ('activityId','datetime','transducerId'))`. Thanks for looking at this.  I'll redesign.

Comment: @Zobal: I don't think there's anything wrong with the table design; I think the performance problem is all the inline views, and all the join operations on the unindexed temporary MyISAM tables. With an appropriate covering index, (or an appropriate cluster key, for InnoDB, you should be able to return an equivalent resultset fairly efficiently, using a query similar to the one in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those derived tables are going to eat your lunch, along with your lunchbox, in terms of performance. Those inline view queries get run, and materialized as temporary MyISAM tables, and then the outer query references the temporary MyISAM tables, which are not indexed, to do all the join operations.

As an alternative, consider using just one shot through the table, for a nearly equivalent result. (In your query, if a row for a datetime is "missing" for any of the transducers, no row is returned.

Consider using a `GROUP BY` operation, which MySQL may be able to optimize using an appropriate index.

As an example, something like this:

```
SELECT d.datetime
     , MAX(IF(d.transducerId = 301,d.calculatedValue,NULL)) AS `301`
     , MAX(IF(d.transducerId = 302,d.calculatedValue,NULL)) AS `302`
     , MAX(IF(d.transducerId = 302,d.calculatedValue,NULL)) AS `302`
     , MAX(IF(d.transducerId = 303,d.calculatedValue,NULL)) AS `303`
     , MAX(IF(d.transducerId = 304,d.calculatedValue,NULL)) AS `304`
     , MAX(IF(d.transducerId = 305,d.calculatedValue,NULL)) AS `305`
     , MAX(IF(d.transducerId = 305,d.calculatedValue,NULL)) AS `306`
     , MAX(IF(d.transducerId = 305,d.calculatedValue,NULL)) AS `307`
     , MAX(IF(d.transducerId = 305,d.calculatedValue,NULL)) AS `308`
     , MAX(IF(d.transducerId = 305,d.calculatedValue,NULL)) AS `309`
     , MAX(IF(d.transducerId = 305,d.calculatedValue,NULL)) AS `310`
     , MAX(IF(d.transducerId = 305,d.calculatedValue,NULL)) AS `311`
     , MAX(IF(d.transducerId = 305,d.calculatedValue,NULL)) AS `312`
     , MAX(IF(d.transducerId = 305,d.calculatedValue,NULL)) AS `313`
     , MAX(IF(d.transducerId = 305,d.calculatedValue,NULL)) AS `314`
  FROM `data` d
 WHERE d.activityId = 74 
 GROUP BY d.datetime
```

(You can move the d.datetime to the end of the SELECT list, I just usually have the GROUP BY columns first.)

If there isn't an appropriate index available, this query is going to furiously blow smoke like a heavy freight train struggling up a steep grade.

The most appropriate index for this query is likely going to be

`(activityID,datetime,transducerId,calculatedValue)`

If this is an InnoDB table, and the leading columns in the cluster key are `(activityID,datetime)`, that would be sufficient.

Ideally, the EXPLAIN output for this query to show "Using where; using index" in the Extra column. What we definitely don't want to see in EXPLAIN is a "Using filesort" operation, or any derived tables, where we can help it.

---

This query differs slightly from the original; if a row is "missing" for a particular transducer at at particular datetime, this query is going to return a row for that datetime, but with a NULL value for the "missing" transducer, where the original query would omit the entire row.

---

If you did want to go with `JOIN` operations, then an equivalent that does not make use of inline views would be more efficient than the original, though possibly not as efficient as the GROUP BY query (in my answer above).

```
SELECT cd301.datetime
     , cd301.calculatedValue AS `301`
     , cd302.calculatedValue AS `302`
     , cd303.calculatedValue AS `303`
     , cd304.calculatedValue AS `304`
     , cd305.calculatedValue AS `305`
     , cd306.calculatedValue AS `306`
--     , cd307.calculatedValue AS `307`
--     ...
--     , cd314.calculatedValue AS `314`
  FROM `data` cd301
  JOIN `data` cd302
    ON cd302.activityId   = cd301.activityId
   AND cd302.datetime     = cd301.datetime
   AND cd302.transducerId = 302
  JOIN `data` cd303
    ON cd303.activityId   = cd301.activityId
   AND cd303.datetime     = cd301.datetime
   AND cd303.transducerId = 303
  JOIN `data` cd304
    ON cd304.activityId   = cd301.activityId
   AND cd304.datetime     = cd301.datetime
   AND cd304.transducerId = 304
  JOIN `data` cd305
    ON cd305.activityId   = cd301.activityId
   AND cd305.datetime     = cd301.datetime
   AND cd305.transducerId = 305
  JOIN `data` cd306
    ON cd306.activityId   = cd301.activityId
   AND cd306.datetime     = cd301.datetime
   AND cd306.transducerId = 306
 WHERE cd301.transducerId = 301
```

Obviously, that would need to be extended to get 307, 308, ... 314 following the same pattern.

Again, this JOIN approach might be equivalent to, or even faster than the GROUP BY, though the EXPLAIN will have a lot more lines, compared to the single line GROUP BY plan.

Comment: This is much faster.  As mentioned above, I haven't defined any  indices for the data table other than `PRIMARY KEY ('activityId','datetime','transducerId'))`.  I am running an InnoDB engine.  EXPLAIN has "Using where" in the Extra column.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: EXPLAIN should have a single line, and won't show "Using index" if the "key" col shows "PRIMARY"; "keylen" should be the length (in bytes) of the `activityId` column, and "ref" should show "const". And that's about as good as you are going to get with this query.

Comment: I don't understand what the MAX part of this does.  I see that the query doesn't work without it, but I don't understand what it's MAX-ing.

Comment: Check mark in all of the EXPLAIN columns you mentioned above.  Thanks again.  This is way better.

Comment: @Zobal: The `GROUP BY` is effectively "collapsing" all the rows with the same datetime value into one row; the IF() function in the expression checks the tId on each row, and returns either value, or a NULL. Out of the 14 rows, the IF() returns the value for one row, and NULL for the rest. MySQL needs to pick one row to return a value from, the MAX aggregate function is a convenient way for us to choose the one non-NULL value out of all the NULLs. Remove the MAX aggregates and the GROUP BY, and you'll see all fourteen rows, the IF() is choosing which output column the value is returned in.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for clarifying that for me.  I ran both solutions you provided, and they were equivalent, though I'm not using a massive amount of data yet.  Thanks again!